# onPostExecute method recevied null

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to pass the `ArrayList<ItemDTO> data` to the `onPostExecute` method  but `null` is always being passed to `onPostExecute()` method . I have debugged it as you can see in the screenshot below the `doInBackground` returns arrayList with 2 elements with `long, lat, route, direction` values. How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

**GetLLRD class:**

```
public class GetLLRD {
    Context mContext;
    String json;

    public void post_selected(String json, Context context) {
        this.json = json;
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);
        context = this.mContext;
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<ItemDTO>> {
        ArrayList<ItemDTO> data;


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ItemDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

          .
          .
          .
          .

                                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (ItemDTO itemDTO : data) {
                    double latitude = itemDTO.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = itemDTO.getLongitude();
                    int route = itemDTO.getRoute();
                    String direction = itemDTO.getDirection();
                    System.out.println(latitude + ", " + longitude + ", "
                            + ", " + route + ", " + direction);

                }
          .
          .
          .
          .     


            return data;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDTO> result) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);
                    System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
                }
            }, 1*30 * 1000);

            if (result != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Map.class);
                intent.putExtra("list",result);
                mContext.startActivity(intent); 

            }else{
                Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the dat is null in the GETLLRD class!!!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**MapDataJSON:**

```
public class MapDataJSON {
    ArrayList<ItemDTO> items;

    public MapDataJSON(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemDTO> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public static class ItemDTO  implements Serializable  {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        int route;
        String direction;

        public ItemDTO(double latitude, double longitude, int route,
                String direction) {
            super();
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.route = route;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public int getRoute() {
            return route;
        }

        public String getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public void setRoute(int route) {
            this.route = route;
        }

        public void setDirection(String direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }
    }

}
```

**JSON simple:**

```
[
  {
    "latitude": 20.123456,
    "longitude": 70.123456,
    "route": 4,
    "direction": "ABC"
   },

   {
    "latitude": 30.123456,
    "longitude": 80.123456,
    "route": 9,
    "direction": "DEF"
   },
     {
    "latitude": 10.123456,
    "longitude": 90.123456,
    "route": 3,
    "direction": "GHI"
   }

]
```

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of the JSON data you are trying to process

Comment: why are you empting data into itemDTO and then return data and is that retrieved data in the image is in doInBackground method?

Comment: @Ahmad Alsanie: I am getting JSON string from the server and I have to store the data in arrayList before passing it. Yes it the retrieved adat is in the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: 'but null is always being passed to onPostExecute() method' ??? What do you mean? What is relevant is the value of parameter result of onPostExecute. rusult will be null when data is null during a catch.

Comment: did you try to receive it as a String instead of ArrayList then using a for loop you can empty it in an arrayList  !!

Comment: @greenapps: I thought the return value of `doInBackground` is being passed to `onPostExecute()`? And can I passed data to onPostExecute when null is always being passed?

Comment: Your first remark is correct. I do not understand the second one. 'for (ItemDTO itemDTO : data) {'. You did not tell if you see the values printed by this loop. What is bad in your code is that you even execute this loop when data == null. That will be the case if the catch right above it would occur. You should return null from that catch.

Comment: @ greenapps: I can see the value printed in  the loop.  And  how can I pass data to onPostExecute when null is always being passed?

Comment: So onPostExecute is called it seems. As data is a private arraylist of your asynctask you can directly inspect/use it in onPostExecute instead of parameter result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have tested it yet, but you can try to set your argument passing into the `onPostExecute()`
to

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<ItemDTO> result)
```

instead of

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDTO> result)
```

Comment: I have changed it before from List to Arraylist and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below given code in doingbackground method.

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<ResponseDetail> countriesResponseList = new ArrayList<ResponseDetail>();
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<ResponseDetail>>(){}.getType();
            try {
                countriesResponseList = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), collectionType);
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: With your code I am getting null for data with my code I have contetent in data.

Answer (score 0):

what I have done in the below code is returning the whole `Json` response as a `String` then convert it into `JsonArray` and loop around it and extract each one of the objects and adds it to an `ArrayList`.

Same objective different approach.

**Code:**

```
 class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ArrayList<ItemDTO> data;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                              try {
        // Set up HTTP post

        // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to
        // URLConnection
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(YourURL);

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        // Read content & Log
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
        Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
        e3.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e4) {
        Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
        e4.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Convert response to string using String Builder
    try {
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        inputStream.close();
        result = sBuilder.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("StringBuildingReader",
                "Error convertingt " + e.toString());
    }
    return result;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            JSONArray att = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < att.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jObject = att.getJSONObject(i);
                        double latitude = jObject.getDouble("latitude");
                        double longitude = jObject.getDouble("longitude");

                        int route = jObject.getInt("route");
                        String direction = jObject.getString("direction");

                         ItemDTO itme = new  ItemDTO(latitude,longitude,route,direction);
                        YourArrayList.add(item);

                    }
            //do what ever you need to do with your ArrayList here

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);
                    System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
                }
            }, 1*30 * 1000);

            if (result != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Map.class);
                intent.putExtra("list",result);
                mContext.startActivity(intent); 

            }else{
                Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the dat is null in the GETLLRD class!!!");
            }

        }

    }
```

Hope this will work out for you.